# Google app engine ndb: prevent from using same id

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am building an order system on Google App Engine.

Suppose I have the following model of Order:

```
class Order(ndb.Model):
    time: DateTimeProperty()
```

The date plus a serial number as a string is used as the id of one entity:

```
today = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:10].replace('-','')
# Fetch today's orders
orders = Order.query(...).order(-Order.time).fetch(1)
if len(orders)==0:  # No entities: today's first order 
    orderNum = today + '00001'
else:
    orderNum = str(int(orders[0].key.id())+1)
order = Order(id=orderNum)
order.date = datetime.datetime.now()
order.put()
```

Suppose there are multiple clerks and they may execute the program at the same time. An obvious problem is that they may obtain the same `orderNum` and actually write to the same entity.

How do I do to prevent such situation from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something similar to the code below.

```
@ndb.transactional(retries=3)
def create_order_if_not_exists(order):
    exists = order.key.get()

    if exists is not None:
        raise Exception("Order already exists: ID=%s" % order.key.id())

    order.put()
```

Or you can use Model's class method `get_or_insert()` that transactionally retrieves an existing entity or creates a new one. See details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert).